# LSTM unit in AzureML and Create a Deep Learner using the unit

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, azure-machine-learning-service

How to implement an LSTM unit in AzureML and Create a Deep Learner using the unit?
Is there any implemented unit for LSTM in AzureML?

I should notice that I just found [this sample](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/4b8f1f17e02d4b9ca60486fd56c0fba6) in AzureML gallery.